# Proof that we get equivalent system by applying elementary row operations on a matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

The relevant fact is that any sequence of elementary row operations on a matrix $A$ can be achieved by left-multiplying $A$ by an invertible matrix. (Indeed, you can obtain such a matrix by multiplying the elementary matrices corresponding to the row operations you have performed.) With this fact, we can proceed.

Let $A$ be an $m×n$ matrix, and let $b\in F_m$ be a vector. Also, let $E$ be an invertible m×m matrix. Then, a vector $x\in F_n$ satisfies $Ax=b$ if and only if $(EA)x=Eb$. (This is really a consequence of our being able to multiply $E^{−1}$.) We have shown that the systems $Ax=b$ and $(EA)x=Eb$ are equivalent in the sense that they have exactly the same solutions $x$.

I AM NOT ABLE TO GET :

1. A vector $x\in F_n$ satisfies $Ax=b$ if and only if $(EA)x=Eb$.
2. This is really a consequence of our being able to multiply by $E^{−1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what happens with real numbers. Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, $\forall c\neq0$, we have $$a=b\iff c a= c b$$
Now let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Then, for all $m\times m$ invertible matrix $C$, we have $$a=b\iff Ca=Cb$$
Go back to our question. We have two vectors $Ax,\,b\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and a $m\times m$ invertible matrix $E$. Using the law above, we get

$$Ax=b\iff E Ax=Eb$$Hence, $x$ is a solution of $Ax=b$ if and only if $x$ is a solution of $EAx=Eb$

Now the question is: why the law requires that $C$ is invertible?

If $C$ is not invertible, it still holds that $$a=b\implies Ca=Cb$$
but, it happens that $$Ca=Cb\;\not\!\!\!\implies a=b$$

Hence, if $E$ is not invertible, $$EAx=Eb\;\not\!\!\!\implies Ax=b$$ so a solution to the new system $EAx=Eb$ is not generally a solution to the first system $Ax=b$. Thus the equations $Ax=b$ and $EAx=Eb$ are not equivalent! (i.e they haven't the same solutions).

Comment: <3 thanks :) @framago

Comment: you are welcome, Sahil!